# There is weird artifact inside my model its not letting me sculpt properly!

Tags: sculpting

I made a rat head model from a quad mesh. Then I downloaded an fbx model and deleted its rig armature, resized it and put the rat head on the models head, and booled them together. I sculped the whole body without any problem but ehen i tried to smoothen the joining part of the head to the body. It didnt go well! I just cant smoothen the junction. What do i do? + later i checked that the quad mesh caused some artifacts when i booled them togather  [![i cant smoothen and join this area][1]][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9IsW.png![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9IsW.png!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T921Q.png)[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Use screengrabs, not photos from your phone, they are very low quality and hard to read. In blender go to the main menu> Window > Save Screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

using the simplify brush and smooth you should be able to smoothen the transition.

[image]

Another possibility would be some uneven normals or just a corrupted boolean operation. Therefore check out your normal direction and check your topology in wireframe view.

[image]

if none of those are helping, pease upload some further details by editing your question. Uploading a file is often also helpfull.

Comment: Okay ill try but how do i upload my blend file here?  

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: from your new stills it looks like your boolean operation failed. But ill have to take a look at the file to hopefully tell you why.

Comment: How do i give u my blend file?

Comment: check out the link, its a solution for adding a file to your question in blender stack exchange